# Netsh wlan hostednetwork, who is connected?

Tags: connection, wifi, virtual, host, netsh

I have created a virtual Wi-Fi adapter by command

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=MyHotspot key=MyPassword
netsh wlan start hostednetwrok
```

Everything works fine. I just want to ask if there exists a command for monitoring the traffics of this network? I mean I connect by my mobile to this network and I want to get a name of a device that is connected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this can show you the number of devices connected, you need a third party tool to find names of devices:

```
netsh wlan show hostednetwork
```

Comment: Thank you for responce ;))

Yes, I have tried this command, but I need to know these names, Thus that third party. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Is it possible to show the SSID of the client instead of MAC address?

Comment: You suggested third party tool to view the names and other information of the connected devices. Can't we do exactly how third party tools do to gathers information from command?

Answer (score -7):

The command can be :

```
echo connected devices
```

Comment: Hey Man! This is a completely wrong answer. This only echoes `connected devices` . This need not to be here